# How to read form CSV file with blank cells(all cells is strings)

Tags: c, csv

when I load the CSV file and reach the first cell that is blank(NULL) than its reading all of the other cells in this row as a blank(NULL).
Im trying to read every cell in the row to Char variable.
How do I read all of the rows with a blank cells (its location is random)?
the first row in the CSV file is categories and I can read it perfectly because there is no NULL cell in it.

```
char line[1000];
            if(FileSelectPopup ("", "*.csv", "", "ballistic", VAL_LOAD_BUTTON, 0, 1, 1, 0, filename))
                {
                    fp = fopen (filename, "r");
                    int i=0;
                    while(fgets(line, 999,fp))//stop when the file end
                    {

                    sscanf(line,"%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^','],%[^'\n']\n",data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],
                          data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++]);
                    usernum++;
                    i=0;

                    }
                    usernum--;

                }
```

Comment: Not your main problem, but those wall-to-wall `data[usernum][i++],data[usernum][i++]` are undefined and not guaranteed to do what you want.

Comment: Rule #1: If you're doing something at all complicated, `scanf` isn't the way to do it.  Rule #2: If you're trying to do something complicated with a complicated `scanf` invocation, but it's not quite working, the way to fix it is *not* to make the `scanf` invocation even more complicated.

Comment: If you don't have to worry about quoting, a good way to read CSV files is to read lines using `fgets`, then break them into comma-separated fields using `strtok`.  Now, `strtok` can't handle empty fields, either, but if you're taking this approach, the answer is to switch to `strsep`, which *can* handle empty fields.